# Data retrieved from parse not working for checks

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve a string from parse and then i want to check whether that string is "Yes". The string is retrieved properly as i can see the string in the form of a toast, but in the very next line i am checking whether that string is equal to "Yes", and according to the data that i have set in my parse database it should execute the code of that if loop but it just doesn't. Here's the Code

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RequirementCheck");
        query.getInBackground("TVQfYqeX3A", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),parseObject.getString("Requirement")  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG); //I get this toast of Yes
                t.show();
                if (parseObject.getString("Requirement") == "Yes")  {
                    Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t1.show(); //This if code is not executed
                }
                else {
                    Toast t3 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t3.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RequirementCheck");
    query.getInBackground("TVQfYqeX3A", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),parseObject.getString("Requirement")  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG); //I get this toast of Yes
            t.show();
            if (parseObject.getString("Requirement").equals("Yes"))  {
                Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t1.show(); //This if code is not executed
            }
            else {
                Toast t3 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t3.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Notice I replaced == with .equals(). For checking strings you must do .equals() rather than the == operation in Java

== checks if the two objects have the same reference. [string.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) checks if the contents of both string objects are the same. In this case, you are wanting the later of the two.

Comment: You sir are my saviour :)

Comment: Hey no problem, glad I could help :)